# Need to encrypt data sent to browser and decrypt with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption

My project is sending PHI/PII data to the browser and I need to be to prevent someone from seeing it.  How would I encrypt with C# and then decrypt with JavaScript?  I cannot user CryptoJS as it is not allowed here.  Even though the connection is an SSL connection I am being told I need to encrypt the data.  Any ideas?

Comment: @swetansh Isn't that encoding and not encryption?

Comment: @swetansh Have you considered that might be a matter of phrasing, since everywhere else he clearly says _encrypt_?

Comment: These questions are getting somewhat tiresome. The encryption provided by TLS is more secure than any encryption scheme you come up with and implement yourself. It is more than enough. Whoever told you that you need to encrypt the data further doesn't know what they are talking about and should know better than to make security recommendations without being educated on the subject. Further, **do not** use base64 for anything other than it's intended purpose, it provides no security whatsoever. Recommending it is terrible advice... @swetanshkumar

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark - thank you for your response.  When they come to me with complaints that the data is visible, can I send to you???

Comment: @Dean.DePue Simply request proof of that claim.

Comment: Anyone who comes to you with those complaints also fits into the category of "doesn't know what they are talking about".  See above.

Comment: @Dean.DePue HTTPS encrypts all data including the query string, only the server address is not encrypted. You can do no better than HTTPS. Also, you can send "them" to me if they complain that HTTPS is not secure and sufficient.

Comment: Thank you folks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between encrypting and encoding. I would also recommend Base64 as the encoding mechanism, but for data encryption you should really be relying on the SSL connection to transport the encoded data to/from the server as it provides 1024-bit or 2048-bit encryption automatically during transit.

How is the transport being accomplished? What mechanism is being used to send/receive the data? If you're using standard HTTP with GET then the data will be vulnerable at some point during the transaction and should never be used with sensitive data, as the data can be cached and remain in the browser history.

Comment: Basically this system always uses HTTPS and it is within a closed system not open to the public.  I guess the main fear is an in-house bad actor...

Comment: Just remember that any data available to a browser page/script is also available to human eyes. It only takes peeking at the page source and querying variables in the browser's developer console.

Comment: @Dean.DePue Then it's an organizational problem, not a technical one.